How much water do I need to drain after I replace Whirlpool RO Membrane and Filters?
How much water do I need to drain after I replace my Whirlpool RO system cartridges? Do I need to drain the entire tank before I swap out the cartridges? There doesn't seem to have instructions on these.


follow the manufacturer's instructions


SANITIZE THE SYSTEM
Sanitizing is recommended immediately after
installation of the Reverse Osmosis system. It’s also recommended
after servicing inner parts. It is important that the person
installing or servicing the system have clean hands while handling
inner parts of the system. Complete the following steps to sanitize
the system. See Fig. 24.

Make sure that the water supply to the Reverse Osmosis system is off.
Open the Reverse Osmosis faucet. If the tank is not already empty, allow the water to empty.
Locate the eyedropper included in parts bag and common household bleach (5.25%).
Add 3 ml. of bleach into open end of yellow tubing. Handle bleach according to bleach manufacturer’s recommendations. See Fig. 24.
Connect yellow tubing to tank connector. See Figs. 13 and 24.
Sanitizing the system will be completed during the pressure test and purging steps on the following page. NOTE: The bleach must be
removed from the system before drinking the water.

PURGING THE SYSTEM
To purge the system, complete the following steps.

Open the Reverse Osmosis Faucet and let water flow through the system for a 24 hour period. Water flow will be a slow trickle at this
time. NOTE: Do not consume water from the RO system until purging is
complete.
Close the Reverse Osmosis faucet after the 24 hour purging period is complete.
When the purging is finished, your Reverse Osmosis system is ready for use.


https://www.whirlpoolwatersolutions.com/wp-content/manuals/WHER25/Reverse%20Osmosis%20System.pdf

Should I replace the cartridges then let water flow through the system for a 24 hour period? What about the water the was already in the water tank? Is there something I can test the water before I know it's safe to drink?

I only know what's in that document. Why wouldn't it be safe if you followed the sanitization process?
